# Streaming from Spring CrudRepository via RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller, spring-webflux

I am trying to stream large dataset from CrudRepository via RestController. I am using HSQLDB for the test. However, no matter what I do, I cannot make it work. First I tried with streams:

### Stream attempt

#### Repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    @Query("select p from Person p")
    Stream<Person> streamAll();
}
```

#### RestController

```
@RestController
public class PersonRestController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @GetMapping("stream")
    public StreamingResponseBody getPersonsStream() {

        return new StreamingResponseBody() {
            @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
            @Override
            public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                try (
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
                        Stream<Person> stream = personRepository.streamAll()
                ) {
                    stream
                            .map(person -> person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName())
                            .forEach(name -> {
                                writer.println(name);
                                writer.flush();
                            });
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

but it did not work. Spring complained about missing read-only transaction no matter what I did.

Then I tried with WebFlux:

### WebFlux attempt

#### Repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    @Query("select p from Person p")
    Flux<Person> fluxAll();

}
```

#### RestController

```
@RestController
public class PersonRestController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @GetMapping(value = "stream", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Person> getPersonsStream() {

        return personRepository.fluxAll();
    }
}
```

Here I got

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [reactor.core.publisher.Flux<?>]
```

Is there a simple way to stream data from repository via RestController?

Comment: For what it's worth, the first error looks like a threading issue (the two `@Transactional` annotations may be looking in different places), and this use case should probably be explicitly addressed in the docs.

Comment: I tried to put none, just the first, just the second, and both, but none of them worked.

Comment: The outer Transactional is useless, because a different thread is executing the writeTo method. The inner Transactional is ignored, because it's annotating a method of an object that is not a Spring bean. Move the content of the writeTo method to a method of another Spring bean, annotated with Transactional, and call that Spring bean method from the StreamngResponseBody's writeTo method.

Answer (score 0):

In your WebFlux attempt, the `PersonRepository` needs to extend `ReactiveCrudRepository`.

Comment: That causes `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property saveAll found for type Person!`

Comment: That's because it requires a Publisher<Person>; check out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.java

Answer (score -1):

this is how I made it.

The repository

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c")
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "0"))
public Stream<Customer> streamAll();
```

The service

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void streamAll(final OutputStream outputStream) {
  try {
    final Stream<Customer> stream = customerRepository.streamAll();
    objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, stream);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}
```

The controller

```
@GetMapping("/stream")
@ResponseBody
public StreamingResponseBody streamAll() {
  return outputStream -> customerService.streamAll(outputStream);
}
```